# "web-site" tag should probably be changed to "website".

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This question contains the [web-site](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-site) tag:

> [Are there ways to easily convert chapter-split books from popular fan-fiction sites into single e-book?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/219/are-there-ways-to-easily-convert-chapter-split-books-from-popular-fan-fiction-si)

However, website is almost always written without a hyphen, according to [Google Trends](http://www.google.ca/trends/explore#q=website%2C%20web-site&cmpt=q):

[image]

Therefore, I would suggest creating the [website](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) tag and setting [web-site](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-site) as a synonym.

Comment: As the tag creator, I'm in favor of this rename.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. (every question deserves an answer :)